# Recommendations for CUDA Fortran IDE

Tags: ide, debugging, gpu, fortran

Ideally I am looking for an open source IDE for CUDA Fortran development. However I am also open to non-open source recommendations. I am particularly looking for a good debugging functionality.

I have read somewhere that Eclipse Photran supports CUDA Fortran in some way? Can anyone provide any clarification on this?